# Poisson regression with limited range DV

Tags: time-series, poisson-regression

I’m planning a study to collect number of weeks our participants are employed each month (during 1 year time period) for an interrupted time series analysis. Thus, the dependent variable is limited to values 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4 weeks. Should I be concerned about using a Poisson distribution for such a limited range of values? Would it be better to collect employment for each week (or biweekly) as yes/no and use a logistic regression? Thanks!!